# Overloading Operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I need your help, please have a look at the following code I get error
as following:

> no match for operator *(operand types are'doubles and 'lists')

this is inherited class, header file(before operator* function it worked properly)

```
    class lists:public vectorebi
{
public:
    lists (double first_);
    lists (double first_, lists var_);
    double operator-(const double& answer);
    lists operator*(const lists &answer) const;
    virtual ~lists(){};
private:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, lists& arg);
    double first;
    lists* var;
};



 //soucre file
 lists::lists(double first_){
    first=first_;
}
lists::lists(double first_, lists var_){
    first=first_;
    var=&var_;

}
double lists::operator-(const double& answer){
    double result = answer - first;
    return result;
}

lists lists::operator*(const lists &answer) const
{
    lists k = first * answer.first;
    return k;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, lists& arg) {

    os << "(" << arg.var  << ")";
    return os;

}
and the main ///
int main()

{
    double answer1 = 15;

    lists k=5;

    lists answer = k * answer1; //here is an error as compiler points

    cout << answer;

    return 0;
}
```

I will appreciate your help, I am trying to multiply variable of type my class and double, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a binary operator, meaning it expects 2 arguments.
When you say `a * b`, `a` becomes the first (left) argument and `b` becomes the second (right) argument. Effectively the function call looks like `a.operator*(b)`.

You are doing, `answer1 * k` which evaluates to the call `answer1.operator*(k)` . This means `double` must have `operator*` overloaded for `lists`.

But you want it for your class `lists`. So you must do this in `main()`:

`lists answer = k * answer1;`

And `operator*` must be declared as:

```
lists lists::operator*(const double& answer)
{
    lists k = first * answer; // not sure how double * double equals lists
    return k;
}
```

EDIT:

Regarding the error

> lists* lists::var is private within this context

which you pointed out in the comments, it appears because of the inconsistent declaration of `friend operator<<`.

You have declared it as:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const lists& arg); // note the `const` for `arg`
```

But you have defined it as:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, lists& arg) // `const` missing!!
{
    ....
}
```

Just add `const` in the definition as well, and it will work as expected.

Comment: and it should be called in main in the same way as it is now? because when I changed I get error like : lists* lists::var is private within this context

Comment: I already mentioned how to call it in `main()`, like this: `lists answer = k * answer1;`

Comment: That is definitely not related to this, because `var` which is a `private` member of `lists` is not being used in the flow of `operator*`

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
lists answer = answer1 * k;
```

fails because the compiler is looking for a `*` overload on a `double` that takes `lists` instance. This method doesn't exist, but you can define it my creating the method outside your class:

```
lists operator*(double lhs, const lists &rhs)
{
  return lists(lhs) * rhs;
}
```

NOTE: I've made `rhs` a const as this is best practice for operator overloads like this which do not (and should not) modify their inputs:

```
lists operator*(const lists &answer) const;
```

in the declaration and:

```
lists lists::operator*(const lists &answer) const
{
    lists k = first * answer.first;
    return k;
}
```

in the implementation.

NOTE: I think you meant to multiple by `answer.first` and otherwise the code doesn't make much sense.

Also, your streaming operator currently tries to output `var` which is a member variable you never initialize. I suspect you want to output `first` so change it to this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const lists& arg) 
{
    os << "(" << arg.first  << ")";
    return os;
}
```

I've made `arg` `const` as this is the recommended practice. You'll need to update your class definition to reflect this.

Comment: still I get the error and now error is no match with operator*, can I include this method inside the class?? if no why?

Comment: @natia - you can't include the method in the class as the left side of the call is a `double`, and if it's inside the class then the left side would be a `lists` instance.

Comment: @natia - change the method in your class to take a `const`. I'll update the answer to show this.

Comment: well I have included inside the class as well, but it does not work either. 
now I understand why it will not work so I included just in source file but still error. I will appreciate if you can help me out.

Comment: I still get a lot of errors, I have added this code too change in main but doesnt work

Comment: @natia - Without seeing what you've changed the code to it's hard to diagnose the error. It's not helped by the fact that the question code contains issues (lack of const, uninitialized variables) that make it hard to infer whats going on.

Comment: Dear Sean I have updated the code here, and now it runs but result is not as it is supposed to be

Comment: @natia - ok, so tell us what the result is suppose to be..!

Comment: result has to be multiplication of 15*5 = 75 but I get <0xffffff>

Comment: @natia - that's becuase your `*` function multiplies `first` but your `<<` overload outputs `var`, which you never initialize. I'll add an update to show the output.

Comment: Can we modify in a way to multiply my class variable lists to any double?

Comment: @natia - that's your job! I'm happy to help you work out why your multiplication wasn't working, but I'm not here to do your work for you!

Comment: I know, I am not asking to write it down for me, just its really blurry for me to work with overloads and u know.what ever I tried I get errors and can not figure out what I am doing wrong. and errors are not informative enough, even could not fix that previous <0xffffff> one as well.